# Best way to sign (-S) each commit during an interactive rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, gpg-signature, git-interactive-rebase

If you are doing an interactive rebase (eg: `git rebase -i HEAD~3`) and you modify n-2 [aaaa]:

```
e aaaa commit message for n-2
pick bbbb commit message for n-1
pick cccc commit message for n
```

After you are done editing (`git commit -S --amend`), even if you used -S when you committed bbbb and cccc originally, they will no longer be verified because you modified a previous commit. Is there an easier way to sign bbbb and cccc instead of amending every commit in the chain like this:

```
e aaaa commit message for n-2
e bbbb commit message for n-1
e cccc commit message for n
```

and running

`git commit -S --amend --no-edit && git rebase --continue` for each commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Git it's pretty much always a good idea to check for a config that sets it up to work the way you want.

Found by saying `git help config` and `/commit.*sign`:

```
git -c commit.gpgsign=true rebase
```

or just `git config --global commit.gpgsign true`.

Comment: [`git rebase --gpg-sign`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--Sltkeyidgt).

Comment: @phd I tried using -S [aka --gpg-sign] with -i and it wasn't working.

Comment: @jthill Adding it to the config worked! Thank you!!!

Comment: if `-S` doesn't work with  `-i` I'd hazard that's not so much a bug as an exceptionally-difficult-to-overcome engineering limit.